# Make python consider a quoted string as a block

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pyparsing

I'm making a grammar using `Pyparsing` and want to make it parse all the inserts, even those having a date.
I don't get how to make the `quotedStrings` an entire block.

```
ident          = Word( alphas, alphanums + "_$" ).setName("identifier")
number         = Word(nums)

quotedString = "'" + delimitedList(number | ident , ".", combine=True) + "'"
quotedStringList = Group(delimitedList(quotedString))

insert_statement <<= (INSERT + INTO + tableNameList + VALUES + delimitedList(openingparenthese + quotedStringList + closingparenthese) + Optional(endLine))

data = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('2008-07-28 00:00:05', 'a');"
print (data, "\n", insert_statement.parseString( data ))
```

I expect to get something like :

```
['insert', 'into', ['test'], 'values', '(', ["'", '2008-07-28 00:00:05', "'", "'", 'a', "'"], ')', ';']
```

But I only get :

```
Expected "'"
```

Comment: Escape with \, like `"INSERT INTO test VALUES(\'2008-07-28 00:00:05\', \'a\');"`

Comment: I want to make it work automatically without changing the data because the lines will come from external files

Comment: The opening and closing parentheses should be outside the `delimitedList`, not inside. As it is, you are saying you expect a delimited list of values and each value is in parentheses.

Comment: Why not use [sqlparse](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this mistake will happen to many people, but the easiest way to have quoted Strings...is to use the one given by pyparser
`from pyparser import quotedString, ... as pp` instead of trying to create your own

Thanks for the replies anyway, helped me for other problems

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment so I must create an answer 
Try to use the 
    `str(text).replace ("'", "\'")`
Method or with regex

```
import re
re.sub(re.compile("'"),"\'", str(text))
```

I'm not at keyboard, so be patient.
But I hope it can help someway

Comment: "I cannot comment so I must create an answer", no do **not post comments as answers*. If you do not have enough rep to comment, don't break the rules and write a comment in an answer. Just wait until you have enough rep to comment.

Comment: The tip can be useful, I honestly don't understand the "-1".